# Why do I have to have my package name scattered EVERYWHERE

Tags: java, android

At the top of every java class I define in it's own file I declare my package's name as in

```
package ss.myPackageName;
```

I define a class in there as in

```
public class MyClass
```

Then in another code file I want to use use MyClass, as in

```
public MyClass x;
```

But I can't.  I have to use "ss.myPackageName.MyClass" everywhere I want to use MyClass.   I have read that it isn't necessary if it's all in the same package but I can't figure it out. This makes my code difficult to read.  I already made the package name shorter.  Is this special to Android or Android Studio, or is it just something I need to learn about java?  (minimal java experience here)

Comment: This is something you need to learn about Java: You don't have to qualify class names from the same package, and if you using `import` statements, you don't have to qualify class names from other packages. See [The Java™ Tutorials - Using Package Member](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html).

Comment: It'd be useful to see screenshots and a [mcve]

Comment: Does your other code file also have `package ss.myPackageName;` at the top? If not then you need to `import` it.

Comment: Thanks Andreas.  I put "package ss.myPackageName;" on top of every java file.  But even though every single java file declares that same package name, it is still necessary for me to use "import ss.mypackagename.MyClass;" or else every instance of MyClass shows up as colored red in the editor.  From the settings, it looks like red represents "unknown type"

Comment: 4castle - yes, I have package "ss.myPackageName" on top of every java file.  It compiles and runs, but every appearance of "MyClass" in the editor is colored red indicating that it is an unknown type.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do `import ss.myPackageName.MyClass` and then use `MyClass`.

Comment: Much more than the comments I get from the people who say "Give us the source code for your entire project" instead of actually trying to help given 100% of the relevant lines of code.